# A question about Rademacher system

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Prove that Rademacher system $\{r_n=sign(\sin(2^n\pi t)\}$ is not complete system in $L_2[0,1]$. I have some problems with proving this. I think, I should take a function $f\ne0$ such that $<f,r_n>=0$. I have no idea how to choice such function

Comment: If $n=0$ is excluded, then $f=1$ will do.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a hint.  Try $f=r_1 r_2$. More generally, try sketching the graphs of as many of the $r_n$ as you can without getting bored, and see if you can spot why this suggested $f$ is orthogonal to all the $r_n$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! But can I do it without graph? How to calculate this integral $\int_0^1r_1r_2r_n$?

Comment: Why does $r_1\cdot r_2$ orthogonal to all $r_n$ shows that $(r_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ is not complete in $L_2[0,1]$?

Comment: @Manatee The nonzero vector $r_1\cdot r_2$ is not in the linear span of the $r_n$. Because the formula $r_1\cdot t_2=\sum_n \langle r_1\cdot r_2,r_n\rangle r_n$ fails.